# I keep getting flat tires on my E-bike

Tags: tire, puncture, electric-bike

I got my first flat a month ago and it was a snakebite flat. I got it by hitting a small bump on the road with low tire pressure.

Since then I keep getting flats after a few days of riding. Every time I switch the tube and it's always tiny holes. I checked for anything in the tire, the rim seems fine and I always ride with the tube completely inflated ever since.

This is my 3rd flat now. I even tried switching tube brands. I'm pretty sure I installed them correctly.

Any idea why this is happening?

This is the tire:

[image]

Comment: If your tube is pinched, increase the tire pressure. If your tire does not allow for more pressure, use a better tire. If your tire is punctured by stones/glass fragments/whatever, invest into some puncture resistant tires. Especially with E-bikes, there is absolutely no reason not to use puncture resistant tires, and they are worth every penny they cost extra.

Comment: Also, if you have a punctured tire, you must search and find the stone/glass/whatever that did it and remove it from the tire when you replace the tube. Because otherwise, that same stone/glass/whatever will just punch a new hole into the new tube...

Comment: Consider patching your tubes, don't just bin them because of a simple puncture.  Its cheaper, and your tyre becomes slightly thicker in those spots.  I only replace tubes when two patches would overlap, or valve damage, or the hole is a split and too big to patch.

Comment: If change a flat, and don't find the reason for the flat, you will get the same flat again.  After removing the tire, remove the tube and note it's orientation to the tire AND wheel.  Find the hole, inspect the area the hole occurred in, fix, enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

You have addressed the pinch flat problem by running higher pressure.

If you are getting repeated punctures, even with new tubes, there is probably something still in the tire that is causing the tiny holes.

Finding the offending object can be difficult. I was unfortunate enough to pick up a tiny piece of steel wire (possibly a bit of paper staple) in my rear tire recently that just protruded into the tube. I had to carefully inspect both the inside and outside of the tire to find it.

Comment: Finding a repeating puncture is the reason for always putting the label/printing on the tyre above the valve hole on the rim. That way one can easily see if the second puncture is at the same place.

Comment: @Carel excellent point

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus Yea I checked the tire thoroughly and couldn't find anything. But there is a very slight tear on the inside that doesn't actually go through the tire and its around the place the hole is on the tube. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Take off the tube and run your thumb on the entire surface of the inner tire.

If you can, keep track of where the puncture on the tube is with respect to the tire, and start looking there.

With your thumb your should be able to feel any spike playing nasty tricks with your tube. Once you have found it, take it out.

Comment: using a balled up rag of old cloth, works better, since your thumb or any part of your hand may get injured when running it on the inside of the tire while searching for a pointy object.